# bintohex() and random_bytes() functions are undefined in PHP 5.6 on Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I'm trying to call

```
echo bintohex(random_bytes(30));
```

But my logs show

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function bintohex()
```

PHP 5.6.17
Apache 2.2.15
CentOS 6.7
Mcrypt 2.5.8 *(installed and verified on phpinfo() page)*
extension=mcrypt.so *(present)*

Any ideas why I can't find bintohex() or random_bytes() functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it **bin2hex** http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php not "bintohex"

**random_bytes** basically exist only in Php 7 according to docs http://php.net/random_bytes but here is polyfill to 5.x version https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Comment: Also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Comment: Yup, forgot that one, thanks